# Xcode/Firebase Improving search function

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, searchbar

I'm new to both Xcode and firebase.
I made this search bar yesterday, but I only had it to search for one thing (String). And now I'm asking how to search for all the data.
The data is from firebase and is both numbers and text look it:

```
"Fornavn" - Text,
"Efternavn" - Text,
"Personnr" - Numbers
```

The code:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class FindTableViewController: UITableViewController, 
UISearchResultsUpdating {

@IBOutlet var FindTableView: UITableView!

let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

var usersArray = [NSDictionary?]()
var filteredUsers = [NSDictionary?]()
var databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    databaseRef.child("Buyers").queryOrdered(byChild: "personnr").observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
    self.usersArray.append(snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)

        self.FindTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self.usersArray.count-1,section:0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)

    })
    { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

And here is the function:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    filterUsers(searchText: self.searchController.searchBar.text!)
}

func filterUsers (searchText:String) {
    self.filteredUsers = self.usersArray.filter{ user in

        let username = user!["Fornavn"] as? String

       return(username?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!

   }

    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Any clue on how to search for more than "Fornavn", text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
func filterUsers (searchText:String) {
    self.filteredUsers = self.usersArray.filter{ user in
        var searchResultForUserName = false
        var searchResultForSecondSearch = false 
        var searchResultForThirdParam = false
        if let username = user!["Fornavn"] as? String {
               searchResultForUserName =  username.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }
        if  let secondSeachedStr = user!["Efternavn"] as? String {
                   searchResultForSecondSearch =  secondSeachedStr.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
       }
       if let number = user!["Personnr"] as? String {

             searchResultForThirdParam = number.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) 
       } 

       return searchResultForUserName || searchResultForSecondSearch || searchResultForThirdParam 


   }

    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Note: Please use optional binding to unwrap optionals in your code

Comment: Okay, and what about when it isnt a string. What if it is number?

Comment: @JonasLarsen see my updated answer, see if helps you solve your problem

Comment: I get an error trying to run just "Efternavn" aswell.
"EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION"
The error is at the return statement

Comment: Do you have an idea about it?

Comment: @JonasLarsen I think error is due to force unwrapping , see my updated answer, does it solve your problem for "Efternavn"

Comment: Sort of.
When I search for "Efternavn" it will search correct, but after 1 second it goes back to xcode and gives an error here at user= fileredUsers (EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION)
    
            user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154757/discussion-between-3stud1ant3-and-jonas-larsen).

Comment: @JonasLarsen Can you show where the error occurs? I have updated the code, please see that you are following it

Comment: Okay, now it works!
However, the number function does not. Does the data have to be shown in the table view for me to search for it?

Comment: @JonasLarsen No it is not necessary, it should only be in the dictionary, are you sure "Personnr" is a number?

Comment: Yes im sure, it is the personal ID

Comment: please try `if let number = user!["Personnr"] as? NSNumber` instead of `if let number = user!["Personnr"] as? Number`

Comment: @JonasLarsen try `if let number = user!["Personnr"] as? String` and comment the `numStr` code and use this `searchResultForThirdParam = number.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) `

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot for all the help. 
I got a last thing (In the chat)

Comment: @JonasLarsen Good, It means that you `user!["Personnr"]` is a string not a number

Comment: Oh ofc, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is not using firebase queries for searching data. 
You can use third party services like Algolia or Elastic Search, and sync you index using Cloud Functions.

Sample of cloud function here: [Full-text search via Algolia](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fulltext-search)

Comment: Its a nice thought, but I can´t use a third party service. So I have to get this to work.
Plus, it looks like I need to pay for this?

Answer (score 0):

Different approach:

1. Make your user equatable
2. Make single parameter query for each field you like to search.

`let databaseQuery = Database.database().reference().child("users")
            .queryOrdered(byChild: "nickname")
            .queryStarting(atValue: query).queryEnding(atValue: "\(query)\u{f8ff}")`

3. Run all queries by observing single `.value` event
4. Use dispatch group to make sure that all queries complete.
5. Combine results in set (for making all founds unique)
6. Sort as you like
7. Display results